# I am getting a java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s' error in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, runtimeexception, spring-resttemplate

I am getting a java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s' error in Java below is my stacktrace:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transformToListClass': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
```

I am passing the below JSON file:

```
{
"EcrionIntegration": {
  "HelloWord": "Hello World"
}
}
```

To the following method:

```
@PostConstruct
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> tranform() {
    try {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
//Use JSONObject for simple JSON and JSONArray for array of JSON.
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Liver\\code\\HELLO_WORLD.json"));//path to the JSON file.

        String payLoad = data.toString();


        ImageDescriptor descriptor = ecrionService.generateImage(payLoad, "HELLO_WORLD");

        log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result: [%s] ", descriptor.getFileName(), descriptor.getFileUrl()));
        System.out.print(descriptor.getFileName() + " " + descriptor.getFileUrl());

        String fileName = "ecrionlList.PDF";
        log.info(String.format("file name:", fileName));
        System.out.print("file name:" + fileName);
        descriptor.setFileName(fileName);

        InputStreamResource streamResource = new InputStreamResource(descriptor.getInputStream());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
                .body(streamResource);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Which is in turn passed to the following method and send to the server:

```
public ImageDescriptor generateImage(String payLoad, String templateName) {
    try {
        ImageDescriptor descriptor = new ImageDescriptor();

        String myEcrionUrl = "http://localhost:8013/v1/ecrion";
      String ecrionURL = myEcrionUrl.concat(Constant.F_SLASH).concat(templateName);



        log.info("payload" + payLoad);

        ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                ecrionURL,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                ncbiService.getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(payLoad),
                Resource.class);
      log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream()));
        descriptor.setInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getBody()).getInputStream());

        convert(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream(), "sherrr.pdf");

        log.info("file is:"+ convert(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream(), "sherrr.pdf"));

        return descriptor;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(" generate image failed " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }




 }
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Yes its is in the first pert of this question, it was edited by saka1029

Answer (score 2):

```java
log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream()));
```

This format has two %s, but you only passed one argument.

Comment: Thanks....so should it be log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream())); or log.info(String.format("generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream())); ?

Comment: Also what does %s mean, I am working on a code done by someone else :) and where am I passing just one argument?

Comment: whatever format you want to use. `%s` indicates where the string representation of the corresponding argument you pass is. If for example the argument is null, the message is either `null generateImage Result` or `generateImage Result: [null]`

Comment: @san, If you think my answer has helped you, you can accept my answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))
String.format accepts Format string and vararg or parameters. If you look at the formatter string [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) you can see that after `%` sign there are a bunch of parameters which can be used to format the string. Particularly for the `%s` it's written the following

```
's', 'S'    general If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().
```

So the error you were getting was because you were telling formatter string that 2 parameters will be formatted and you passed only one of it

```
log.info(String.format("%s generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream()));
```

So you can just remove the first `%s` :

```
log.info(String.format("generateImage Result: [%s] ", responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream()));
```